# Support merging doc examples

Tags: feature-request, documentation, edits

Suppose I want to merge two examples. It might make a big improvement to the documentation, but I have a strong incentive not to do it, since I'll have to delete one example, depriving its authors of future (and past?) rep.

[A concrete example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/481/importing-and-exporting-data#t=201607221524109245265):

[image]

I might want to merge "Exporting CSV file" with "Exporting a csv file" here.

So, I'd like to see some means of merging examples. I know that's a tall order -- affecting the editing UI and how responsibility for examples is retained -- but I think it will make folks a lot less reluctant to consolidate examples (which is a big part of how I imagine improving docs, now that I see the flood of examples).

Comment: Another example: I want this example about a seq() function for constructing sequences to be merged under the already-existing example "Sequence of numbers": http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/29330 Borrowing from and then deleting the new example would not be a nice thing to do.

Comment: That would be a really great feature!

Comment: @Frank really good idea! Maybe some kind of line by line merge like subversion would be really cool.

Comment: **Another example:** It would make sense to merge [Any](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/68/linq-queries/5098/any#t=201707031407283456914) and [All / Any](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/68/linq-queries/2773/all-any#t=201707031407283456914) in the [LINQ queries](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/68/linq-queries#t=201707031412411798812), but deleting one of them means the authors of the deleted topic would lose reputation, while the others would gain reputation. How can this be solved?

Comment: For the example above I found a solution - rewriting both posts so each of the two is providing unique, non-redundant information. But that will not work in all scenarios - so the question is still valid: What to do if you really have to merge two or more chapters (because they are belonging together and need to be one)?

Comment: I wish I could start a bounty for this topic, it did not get enough attention after 1 year. What I am doing now is I am adding a "BUG" flag - hopefully the developers will read this.

Comment: @Matt Please don't tag questions with irrelevant tags merely for more exposure. This is not a bug, it's a feature request.

Comment: Ok, I agree. However, how about introducing something like the bounty in Meta?

Comment: I have another example of two examples that (imo) should be merged: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1396/fragments/19883/animate-the-transition-between-fragments and https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1396/fragments/17598/fragment-transitions. The added wrinkle is that there's an improvement request on this topic, but trying to add an example is giving me an error that the topic has already reached its maximum number of examples. This doesn't seem possible to fix without merging/deleting one of the existing examples.