# How should I handle multiple examples that should have been posted as one?

Tags: discussion, documentation

A user's recently created a [new topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/spring-boot/3398/spring-boot-jpa-mongodb) in the [documentation for `spring-boot`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/spring-boot/topics) where they've posted multiple examples. None of these examples stands on it own and they should have been posted as a single example. To be clear, unlike [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329002/support-merging-doc-examples), this is a single user that's misunderstood how to use documentation examples and, as such, all eight of the examples are useless when each is considered in isolation.

I've discovered in the UI that examples can be moved but I can't see a way to merge them. The least bad option that I've found is to delete the topic and hope that the user starts again but that seems rather extreme. Given the tools currently available in documentation, what's the right way to handle this?

A secondary issue here is that the examples were approved in the first place. In my opinion, the user who approved them is rather eager with their approvals. I also wonder what, if anything, can be done about that.

Comment: @rfkortekaas I can't see the connection between my question and the one which you believe is a possible duplicate. As a result, I'm not sure what edits I can make so that it's clearer. Can you please explain why you think it is a duplicate?

Comment: I've added the wrong link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329002/2345870

Comment: @rfkortekaas That's certainly related, but I believe my question is different. Being able to merge answers would probably solve my problem, but I can't do that just now. Primarily, I'd like to know what I can do about this now. Secondarily, I'd like to know what can be done to stop the examples from having been approved in the first place.