# Seven separate topics explaining C# streams: how should they be combined/managed?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

The [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag on Documentation (not including the [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) tag) has **seven** separate topics that all attempt to explain streams. Three of them have the exact same name (with different contents), most of them duplicate information, and I personally believe that they are mostly low-quality. How should these be handled? And should this information be removed from [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and instead maintained in [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net)?

**https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/4266/file-and-stream-i-o**

This one is mostly about non-stream I/O, but streams are still mentioned. This might be a good candidate to have other examples moved into.

**https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/4265/file-and-stream-i-o**

Two of the examples are about other classes, but one of them (the largest) is about streams. The points made about streams *are* good points; the example shows how to read a large file line-by-line without loading it into memory all at once.

**https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/4324/file-and-stream-i-o**

This one has the same information -- more or less -- about the basic usage of streams as the other ones. It also has an example that makes the same good points as mentioned in the previous description. This topic includes a syntax section which is good, but that syntax list also mentions some completely random classes (starting `Process`es is *not* file I/O in my mind). Also, the "Parameters" section has content, but that content doesn't list parameters.

**https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/3089/streamwriter-write-text-to-a-file**

This topic focuses on the `StreamWriter` class. There is very little explanation and I don't think the topic should be standalone. Again, mostly duped information.

<s>**https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/3670/file-i-o**</s>
**https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/3598/reading-and-writing-to-files** (exact duplicates)

Very similar to the second link. More duplicated information on streams.

**https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/2632/i-o-classes**

Called "I/O classes" but just includes an example for `FileStream`. The example is unclear and confusing.

**https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/3114/stream**

The singular example here is actually pretty nice, but it should probably be broken into smaller separated examples. Also, the name is not very helpful.

Comment: You can ask [one of the 22 pages of people with a silver or gold badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/39/c-sharp) to merge them if you don’t want to go through review.

Comment: @JF That's my goal with asking this question; I want to find someone that both knows what should be done and has the ability to do it, or at least get consensus on what should be done, as I am not confident that I know what needs to happen.

Comment: I would move the examples into the oldest one and then delete the newer/lower quality duplicates (private/incognito tabs may be helpful).

Comment: @JF What do you believe should happen when examples overlap but aren't complete dupes? Edit the info from one into the other and then delete the now-obsolete one?

Comment: That hasn’t quite been figured out yet, but I’d suggest doing that.

Comment: @JF I took your suggestions and have gotten most of this cleaned up. The major topic is now [File and Stream I/O](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/4266/file-and-stream-i-o), which includes most if not all of the information in the topics linked to above (there are still one or two that I need to finish up and delete). Although I think the existing answer is a good feature request, your suggestions were the real answer here; would you be willing to write up an answer explaining what you said in comments so I can mark it?

Comment: Seven blessings to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the examples into the oldest topic and then delete the newer/lower quality duplicates (private/incognito tabs may be helpful to allow you to view the examples/topics you’re deleting).

If the examples aren’t complete duplicates, I’d suggest copy-pasting the newer ones into the older ones until the devs make a tool that does that.

Note that you can ask one of the [22 pages of people with a silver or gold badge in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/39/c-sharp) to merge the topics if you don’t want to wait for review.

Comment: *Just* copy & pasting looses attribution information for the initial content of the example and all edits. That violates the copyright terms for the content.  While you could credit every single contributor, the copy & paste also deprives those that originated the content of any reputation from providing the original example.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that a feature should be added so that people with a gold/silver badge in the topic can merge duplicates. This has been suggested for edits and reviews too in this [update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331663/documentation-update-august-4th?cb=1) and can be applied here as well. Also, they can just have links saying see c# or see .net instead of duplicating the info, especially because further down the line keeping duplicates would require more editing (if it was needed) when it could be avoided.

Comment: This has been added with that update.

Comment: Where does it mention merging topics? That post was about reviews, votes and reputation.

Comment: *Users with a silver or gold tag badge (from Q&A) will skip review when they make an edit to that tag's documentation*. Edits include merging topics.

Comment: @JF Yes, there is merging of topics (by moving examples around), but no merging of examples. Presumably, there are dupe examples across the many topics identified by the OP... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329002

Comment: I think that this would be great, and it should definitely be considered; it would make handling cases like this much easier. I spent way more time than I should've yesterday dealing with the funky workflow required to merge those examples. I am going to accept @JF's answer because it was the direct answer to my question, but I think this feature request should be posted somewhere, because it would be useful in the future.